# regex to capture a number

Tags: regex

i have the following regex `(?x:-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?)` which works for all number in

```
first -1.3 second 1.1e-2 third -1e-2 fourth -10 fith  -0.1 sixth .3 done.
```

but the last one `.3`.

I was trying to make the first group `(?:0|[1-9]\\d*)` optional, but that breaks the regex. How can I make the regex working for all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.  Your *regex* is:

```
-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

You don't need the `(?x:...)` group because your regex has no whitespace in it, and you only need to escape the backslashes when you write the regex in the form of a string literal.  Most responders will know what you mean, but occasionally someone assumes you're trying to match literal backslashes.

Now, what you need to do is add another alternative to the whole regex:

```
-?(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?|\.\d+)
```

If you want to allow an exponent in all cases, do this:

```
-?(?:(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

Everyone, on first encountering this problem, expects there to be a more elegant or clever way, but there isn't.

Comment: thans, that was exactly what i was looking for